# How to bounce a point to hit a line with a certain angle

Tags: javascript, math, game-physics

I have a line and a point, line has an angle `{ angle }` point has a velocity `{ x, y }`, point moves to the line and hits it. At this point I want to change the velocity of the point, as if the point bounces from the line with regard to the line angle. How do I calculate the new velocity of the point based on line angle?

Answer (score 0):

No 'gravity'?  Perfect elasticity?

```
a = angle
b = atan(y/x)  -- angle of 'velocity'
c = 2a-b       -- angle of new velocity
r = sqrt(x*x + y*y)  --  scaling of x,y
v = r * cos(c)
w = r * sin(c)
new velocity = {v, w}
```

(Caveat:  I don't know what `a` is relative to - vertical or horizontal, nor which direction.  And there may be other issues.)

Comment: line has an angle, it could be any angle between horizontal and vertical